How is Alvin Plantinga's concept of sensus divinitatis reconciled with the problem of divine hiddenness in philosophy of religion?
Previously, I asked What kind of epistemology would justify accepting religious claims that lie beyond the reach of scientific and historical verification?, and @Conifold provided an insightful response in the comments:

"Reformed epistemology is a thesis about the rationality of religious belief. A central claim made by the reformed epistemologist is that religious belief can be rational without any appeal to evidence or argument... Plantinga, when wondering how theistic belief might be grounded, suggests that we consider that Calvin may have been right when he said that God has created humans with an inner awareness of himself and it is this sensus divinitatis that is responsible for theistic belief." IEP, Reformed Epistemology.

However, the notion of an innate human awareness of God, referred to as sensus divinitatis, seems counterintuitive given that many people experience God as hidden (see SEP, Hiddenness of God). If God is hidden from many, this appears to conflict with the idea that all humans have an inherent awareness of God's presence.
Did Alvin Plantinga, or any subsequent philosophers of religion, attempt to reconcile the hiddenness of God with the sensus divinitatis that supposedly exists innately within all human beings?
More colloquially: if humans have a sensus divinitatis that enables them to perceive God, why do so many people fail to perceive God? What have philosophers of religion said about this?

Plantinga and other reform epistemologists follow Calvin in explicitly denying Schellenberg’s “divine hiddenness”, that there exist nonbelievers who do not resist God but fail to experience him. They assert that everyone resists to varying degrees (due to corruption by sin), and many are in denial about it, see Helm, John Calvin, the "Sensus Divinitatis", and the Noetic Effects of Sin. It is not unlike Nietzsche’s moral self-delusion or Freud's self-repression of drives or Marx's "false consciousness", but for sensus divinitatis.

There are recent publications about this question. E.g. "Is the Problem of Divine Hiddenness a Problem for the Reformed Epistemologist?"
, "Sensus Divinitatis or Divine Hiddenness?"

To those voting to close: why, and how can I edit to make you retract your close vote?

When considering Calvin, it is always good to see what Hobbes has to say.

If @KristianBerry can't answer it, then I think that rules out John Skeet and Chuck Norris as well. Time for a better question!

The sensus divinitatis, even if it existed, would remain subjective, and hence not suitable for objective analysis. Or in other words, neither Plantiga nor anyone else can tell what everyone else is experiencing in their own minds, just based on what goes on in his own mind. So whether and why such a sense does not work in others would be mere speculation. Apparently Plantiga speculates it's about original sin disturbing the sense. Whatever.
Schellenbergs divine hiddeness argument does not become stronger or weaker when combined with a sensus divinitatis. Even without humans having such a sense, a perfect god would find ways to make all nonresisting humans believers. Such a sense would make gods job easier maybe, but philosophically that's not important. If there is anything (a force, a reason) preventing nonresisting humans from becoming believers, that "anything" can impact the sensus divinatis.

From the introduction of the quoted link IEP reformed epistemology:

Reformed epistemology is a thesis about the rationality of religious
belief. A central claim made by the reformed epistemologist is that
religious belief can be rational without any appeal to evidence or
argument. There are, broadly speaking, two ways that reformed
epistemologists support this claim. The first is to argue that there
is no way to successfully formulate the charge that religious belief
is in some way epistemically defective if it is lacking support by
evidence or argument. The second way is to offer a description of what
it means for a belief to be rational, and to suggest ways that
religious beliefs might in fact be meeting these requirements.


Ad first: It is up to reformed epistemology to argue why religious
belief is epistemic sound if it lacks support by evidence or
argument.
IMO philosophy has no place for claims without argument.

Ad second:  To ask for a definition of rational belief and to suggest
that religious belief meets that definition: It sounds like tailoring
the definition of rational belief such that it covers also religious belief.
IMO that’s not a sincere strategy.


The most simple answer to your final question “if humans have a
sensus divinitatis that enables them to perceive God, why do so many
people fail to perceive God?”:
The premise is false, there is no sensus divinitatis at
all. The concept is a pure ad-hoc speculation with an a awe-inspiring
name. More challenging, but to me also not convincing, is the claim in Paul’s epistle to the Romans 1,19-20.

Neither you nor anyone else can prove the absence of such a sense in everyone else. So it's philosophically unsound to say "there is no sensus divinitatis at all". Rather we would need to say that "there is insufficient evidence for it" or such.

@tkruse As a reply to your comment Russell’s teapot joke comes to my mind. – Please note that the OP asks for an explanation “why do so many people fail to perceive God?” I propose the most simple answer to this question.

You could say: "An obvious simple reason could be if indeed there is no such sense". The OP did not ask if such a sense exists or not though, they are quite aware it's a postulated construct, so that kind of answer is fake, as it expresses something implicit in the question.

So, the Rom 1 quote basically says that we can intuit God's invisible qualities by looking at the visible aspects of the universe, yes? But to me, it fails to ensure that everyone intuits the same things. We can't suddenly see things we have no idea of from our experience. To me, this definitely argues against a sensus divinitatis working flawlessly for everyone. It arises from naive ideas of perception and knowledge.
